# Why do I get this error (NoneType)?

Tags: python

I know there are help forums on the `NoneType` error. But for the love of me I can't save my coding.

```
counter=0
agesList=[]
for line in database:
    newlist=database[counter].split(',')
    counter=counter+1
    age=newlist[-2]
    agesList=agesList.append(age)
    #print(age)
print(agesList)
```

I have a document of comma separated values, and I split them all into their own list and take out the number I'm looking for which sits in the second to last positon of the `newlist`. If I print age I get all of the correct ages 1 by 1 throughout the loop. But if I try to append all of the age numbers onto my blank list I get this error:

```
agesList=agesList.append(age)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Can I please get some help on why I get this error? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `agesList=agesList.append(age)` use only `agesList.append(age)`.

Because `list.append()` returns `None` and overrides your list.

Thus the first iteration of your for-loop will run fine, after that `agesList` is `None` and you will get the error you're mentioning.

Answer (score 1):

You're assigning a function call to your list which is why you're overwriting your list.

Don't do this:

```
agesList=agesList.append(age)
```

Simply do this:

```
agesList.append(age)
```